# Mongoose Schema validation issues when using Array of Mixed [{ }]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-schema

I am building a schema in mongoose (v4.13.8) with an Array of Mixed values. I have come up with the following Schema:

```
var deviceConfigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    capabilities: {
        type: [capabilitySchema],
        required: true,
        validator: [isValidCapabilities, "Not a valid capability array"]
    },
    services: {
        type: [{}],
        required: true,
        validator: [isValidServices, "Not a valid service array"]
    }
});
```

The problem is that I get a validation error saying that `services: Path 'services' is required.` when I try to submit data. What is strange is that the data I send for the  'capabilities' works fine and the only difference is that I specify a schema explicitly.

Removing the `required: true` from `services` causes there to be an empty array object in the returned values.

I am submitting the data using an API POST request with the data in the body of the request. I am using Postman to submit the request, with `x-www-form-urlencoded` checked. This is copied from the body key-value input

```
capabilities[0][field_map][field]:pressure
capabilities[0][field_map][type]:float
capabilities[0][field_map][format]:hPa

services[0][name]:rest
services[0][receive][0][capability_id]:0
services[0][receive][0][path]:/api/relay/0
```

**Update:**

I'd like to apologise as this was a mistake on my part. I dynamically create a configuration based on the request and at one point the copied services were being made null, doh!

However, having got the `required: true` validation to pass, the custom validator is still not being executed. I also can't find any documentation about the order in which validators and are executed which would be very useful. Below is the validator snippet for reference:

```
function isValidServices(services) {
    for (const service of services) {
        if (typeof service.name !== 'string') return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you add code showing how you are submitting data?

Answer (score 0):

Having experimented with various approaches and looking in more detail on the mongoose API docs, I found that there is a `validate` option for schemas too. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate

I changed my Schema **from this**:

```
var deviceConfigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    capabilities: {
        type: [capabilitySchema],
        required: true,
        validator: [isValidCapabilities, "Not a valid capability array"]
    },
    services: {
        type: [{}],
        required: true,
        validator: [isValidServices, "Not a valid service array"]
    }
});
```

**To this** [notice the `validate` instead of `validator`]...

```
var deviceConfigSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    capabilities: {
        type: [capabilitySchema],
        required: true,
        validate: [isValidCapabilities, "Not a valid capability array"]
    },
    services: {
        type: [{}],
        required: true,
        validate: [isValidServices, "Not a valid service array"]
    }
});
```

After this my validator functions were being executed without any issues. Hopefully this helps someone.